# Passdata from file to api endpoint in Json format using React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, object

I have a component that allows users to upload product information through a excel / csv file, I am able to extract that info from the file and display it in a table.
here is the table:
[image]
However i also want to pass that data to the backend in this format:

```
{
"bp_products_information": [
{
    "bp_product_name": "tusker",
    "bp_product_category": "drinks",
    "bp_product_sub_category": "beer",
    "bp_product_unit_of_mass": "500ml",
    "bp_product_buying_price": "200",
    "bp_product_selling_price": 100,
    "bp_product_quantity": 10
  }
 ]
}
```

here is the data i am able to extract:

line 74 shows the headers in the table that i get using the following:

```
sheetdata[sheet][0]
```

and line 69 shows the value i want to pass:

```
sheetdata[sheet].slice(1)
```

sheetdata is the entire csv/excel data while sheet is the number of sheets in the excel document and zero is the index, so tableheaders are at index zero.

[image]

how do you suggest i go through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method can be to loop through all the data rows and construct a new object as required for the api.

```
const headers = sheetdata[sheet][0];
const rows = sheetdata[sheet][1];

const bp_products_information = [];

rows.forEach((row, index) => {

    const product_information = {};

    row.forEach(cell => {
        product_information[headers[index].header] = cell.data
    });

    bp_products_information.push(product_information);

});
```